# A help In the Pivot Method

Tags: sql-server

Help In the pivot method , i dont want to keep writing all the Id is there a way to Like Do it without writing all the id

I dont know how

```
SELECT  'Montant' AS IdClient,
*
FROM
(
SELECT   MontantTransaction,IdClient
FROM   Transactions
) AS TableSource
PIVOT
(
Sum(MontantTransaction)
FOR IdClient IN( [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24])
) AS TableDePivot;
```

i expect to see this code without the ( `[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13]....`

Comment: Have you researched Dynamic Pivot?

Comment: have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Comment: Will you limit your Ids somehow? There's a limit for the amount of columns that SQL Server can return.

Comment: So your profile pic contains an offensive word - and you don't think that is a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

**Sample Temp Table & Data**

```
Create Table #Transactions 
(

    IdClient varchar(3),
    MontantTransaction decimal(10,2)
)

insert into #Transactions values (1, 1000.00)
insert into #Transactions values (1, 200.00)
insert into #Transactions values (2, 800.00)
insert into #Transactions values (2, 700.00)
insert into #Transactions values (3, 1100.00)
insert into #Transactions values (4, 1400.00)
```

**Query**

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.IdClient) 
            FROM #Transactions c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ''Montant'' AS IdClient, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select 
                    MontantTransaction
                    , IdClient
                from #Transactions
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 Sum(MontantTransaction)
                for IdClient in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)

drop table #Transactions
```

Comment: can u please explain for me what does                                                                   SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(NomClient) 
            FROM Client
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

Comment: This will return [1],[2],[3],[4] based on sample table data and which will be used to generate a dynamic pivot table. you can print @cols to see the result.